# How to extend/replace specific chart class methods?

Tags: javascript, apexcharts

I need to modify how a Pie chart in the ApexCharts works, specifically I need to override a "drawArks" method of a Pie class, but I don't seem to have an access to the class. ApexCharts uses some sort of factory function for classes creation, but I am not familiar with such pattern and don't understand if it is configurable. Can I override chart methods?